# Handsontable: adding a column moves colHeaders (how to fix?)

Tags: javascript, handsontable

In the above snippet, a handsontable is created with a hook that adds a column automatically (using `this.alter('insert_col')`) once a user presses "right" in the rightmost column (and also removes an empty rightmost column if a user presses "left" from there). The issue with it, as you may see, is that once a column added in this manner, colHeaders shift to the right instead of staying with their columns. Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong? How do I fix this or is there a workaround?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  var example = document.getElementById('example1'),
      hot = new Handsontable(example,{
    data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(2, 3),
    colHeaders: ["one","two","three"],
    contextMenu: true
  });

Handsontable.hooks.add('beforeKeyDown',function(event)
{
    var $right = 39, $left = 37,
        selected = this.getSelected(),
        isEditMode = this.getActiveEditor().isOpened();
    if(isEditMode) return;

    // calc dimensions
    var startColNum = selected ? (selected[1]+1) : null,
        endColNum   = selected ? (selected[3]+1) : null,
    // endColNum is not necessarily >= startColNum, it is where selection /has ended/
        rowsNum = this.countRows(),
        colsNum = this.countCols(),
        isFirstCol  = endColNum == 0,
        isLastCol   = endColNum == colsNum,
        i, noData, data = this.getData();

    // handle arrow keys
    if(isLastCol) {
        if(event.which == $right)
            this.alter('insert_col');
        if(event.which == $left && !isFirstCol) {
            noData = true;
            for(i = 0; i < rowsNum; i++)
                if(data[i][endColNum-1])
                    noData = false;
            if(noData) {
                this.alter('remove_col');
                Handsontable.Dom.stopImmediatePropagation(event);
                // don't scroll the page
                if(event.preventDefault)
                    event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.10.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.10.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">

<div id="example1" class="hot handsontable"></div>
```

Comment: Specifying the `index` of column to insert seems to fix to issue: `this.alter('insert_col', colsNum);`

Comment: issue added: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/4448

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As IronGeek suggest in the comment, adding the index as the second parameter to the function ***alter*** fix your issue :

```
this.alter('insert_col', endColNum);
```

However, I do believe that you are still right saying that it is a bug since [the documentation](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.33.0/Core.html#alter) specify that if the paramater *index* is null or undefined :

> [...] the new column will be added after the last column.

---

Find this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kzjLoj7/) for quickly testing the fix.